# python package import from different directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
\something\python\
    extras\
        __init__.py # empty file
        decorators.py # contains a benchmark decorator (and other things)
    20131029\   # not a package, this contains the scripts i use directly by doing "python somethingelse.py"
        somethingelse.py
```

And now I want to be able to do something like

```
from .extras import decorators
from decorators import benchmark
```

from inside somethingelse.py

For this to work, where do I need to place `__init__.py` files,  (at the moment, the "\something\python\" path is added to my .tchsrc )

Now, i get the following error:

```
 from .extras import decorators
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Is this a problem with adding it to my pythonpath? or how should I solve this? The current workaround I have is to just copypaste the decorators.py into each new directory i make (if I make a new version of my code, like the "20131029"), but that is just a stupid workaround which means I have to copypaste a lot of stuff each time i make a new version of my code, so a more elegant version with the correct imports is what I want.

Note: I am working in python 2.7, if that makes any difference?

edit: yes, i run it by doing

```
python somethingelse.py
```

more edit: no idea if the way that the benchmark decorator is defined matters? (it is not a class or so, the next thing comes exactly out of the decorators.py file)

```
import time, functools
def benchmark(func):
    """
    A decorator that prints the time a function takes
    to execute.
    """
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t = time.time()
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print func.__name__, time.time()-t
        return res
    return wrapper
```

Edit: if i put the \something\python\extras\ to my pythonpath, i get

```
ImportError: No module named decorators
```

when i run:

```
from decorators import benchmark
```

Does this mean that inside that extras-directory i need to make another subdirectory, in which i than put the decorators.py?

edit: in the .tchsrc, i added the following line:

```
setenv PYTHONPATH /bla/blabla/something/python/extras/
```

and in the somethingelse.py, if i run the following:

```
import sys
s = sys.path
for k in s:
    print k
```

i find that the path /bla/blabla/something/python/extras/ is in that list, so i do not get why it does not work?

Comment: do you run 'python somethingelse.py ' ? python packages do not work that way.

Comment: @georgesl yes, i run it like that, how do i need to make it run so it works like that?

Comment: don't give your packages (i.e. folders with `__init__.py`) names starting with numerals, it will be hard to import them later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `20131029` directory is not a package, so you cannot use relative import paths beyond it.

You could add the `extras` directory to your Python module search path, using a relative path from your current script:

```
import sys, os

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.normpath(os.path.join(here, '../extras')))
```

Now imports look for modules in the `extras` directory first, so use:

```
import decorators
```

Because your directory name itself is using only digits, you cannot make that a package *anyway*; package names must stick to Python identifier rules, which cannot start with a digit. Even if you renamed the directory, and added a `__init__.py` file, you still cannot use it is as package when you run a file within the directory as a script; scripts are always considered to live outside a package. You'd have to have a top-level 'shim' script that imports the real code from a package:

```
from package_20131029.somethingelse import main

main()
```

Comment: but that means that in each file in that module, i need to insert that path, which i dont want to do. What defines which directory is a package and which one is not? I currently have emtpy __init__ files in both directories as well,

Comment: Yeah, the directorynames are a bit unfortunate, but they contain the scripts that will not get imported anywhere, so that does not really matter. The thing is that i want to import the benchmark decorator stored in the 'extras\decorators.py', when executing 'python somethingelse.py'

Comment: When importing from a name, and that name matches a directory on the Python search path, and that directory has a `__init__.py` file, *then* that directory is a package. If loads of scripts use that extras directory, the  perhaps add it to your `PYTHONPATH`. Instead of versioned directories however, why not use a real software versioning system like git or mercurial instead?

Comment: so if i add the extras directory to my pythonpath, in the tchsrc, can i than directly import decorators.py? (how?) I tried that now, but that does not work either?

Comment: I edited the question a bit, with how i try to do it now, but it still does not work.

Comment: *How* are you adding the directory to the `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Also, I *think* you are using a POSIX platform (linux, bsd, mac) as you are using a `.tcshrc` file, but you quote the path using backslashes (which would only work on Windows).

Comment: setenv PYTHONPATH /bla/blabla/python/extras/                   edit: yeah the quotes were just to make it a bit more clear, but apparently that made it more confusing instead.

Comment: And `echo $PYTHONPATH` shows that value in the shell before you start the python script?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40568/discussion-between-usethedeathstar-and-martijn-pieters)